# Getting the price of a woocommerce product inside a FOREACH, and applying a percentage discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field

Im trying to do the following:

I added a text field on the checkout where the customer has to enter a code, if the code is what I want, I apply a discount to the products depending on the category.

The problem I have until now is that I can only apply a fixed fee, I want to apply a percentage fee depending on the individual product price (depending on each product).

Also, right now the text field has not validation on the front end for the customer, how could I add that? I would like for the customer to know if he put the right code or not before checking out.

Thank you!

```
function custom_donation_form() { ?>
        <input type="number" name="card_code" class="input-text" style="display: inline-block !important; width: auto !important;" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Card Code:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="" />        
<?php 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'custom_donation_form', 99 );

function donation_add_fee( $cart ) {    
    if( isset( $_REQUEST["card_code"] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST["card_code"] ) ) {
        if( is_numeric( $_REQUEST["card_code"] ) && $_REQUEST["card_code"] == 1000 ) {
            
            // You need to enter your fees here, in `category slug` => `fee amount` format
            $fees = array(
            'botas'    => 10);
        
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $product_categories = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
            if ( $product_categories && ! is_wp_error( $product_categories ) ) {
                $product_categories = wp_list_pluck( $product_categories, 'slug' );
                
                
                foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $fees[ $product_category ] ) ) {
                        $name      = 'Category fee: ' . get_the_title( $values['product_id'] );
                        $amount    = $fees[ $product_category ];
                        $taxable   = true;
                        $tax_class = '';
                        $cart->add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable, $tax_class );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    }       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'donation_add_fee', 1 );
```

Comment: As you describe your question, it seems strange to use a custom field against the existing coupon field that already contains these functionalities, but I believe you will have your reasons for it. 
Is it the intention that the discount based on the product price is only calculated for products that belong to a certain category or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Im using a separate custom field because I want the coupon field to still work separately from these fees. Yes, I want the discount fee to be calculated as a percentage from the products that belong to a certain category.

Comment: **1/2** I assume you want to keep the view as it is in your current code, by which I mean that the fee is displayed on separate lines per product versus 1 global fee? If this is the case, your current code contains a mistake. Suppose: product A has category-1 and product B has category-1 and category-2. The amount for category-1 is 10 and the amount for category-2 is 15. The output with your current code will be: Category fee: Product A: 10 | Category fee: Product B: 10 while it should be  Category fee: Product A: 10 | Category fee: Product B: 10 | Category fee: Product B: 15.

Comment: **2/2**  This is because when adding the fee, the same naming (without amount) occurs 2x (for product B, category-1 and category-2) so the 2nd time, this is not applied (because the naming already exists). How do you see the solution for this? Isn't it weird to display this per product title versus displaying it per category name?